# Pagination not working at Template Page

Tags: wordpress, loops, pagination

I tried to search right solution for this but I cannot find where I went wrong with code..I want to display pagination on my custom page which uses WP_Query...here is the code:

```
        <?php 
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $frontpageNews = new WP_Query(array(
            'category_name'  => 'recent-news',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'paged'          => $paged,
            'offset'         => 1
        ));             
        while($frontpageNews->have_posts()) {
            $frontpageNews->the_post(); ?>
               the_title();
            }       
        next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
        previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
        ?>
```

My posts are showing but not pagination...Sorry if there is existing topic on this, I just couldnt find one that it helped this case, so I came here to ask.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pagination using following code.

```
<div class="pagination">
<?php 
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
        'total'        => $frontpageNews->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
        'show_all'     => false,
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'end_size'     => 2,
        'mid_size'     => 1,
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => '',
    ) );
?>
```

This is working for me so it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked. I was worried there is a problem with upper code, array or the loop. This isnt the format I was looking for tho, but at least I know where was the problem. Thanks again

Comment: I did, it says I dont have enough reputation to show upvote publicly, however the vote is "casted" whatever that means.